# Sum of infinite sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $$T_r=\frac{rx}{(1-x)(1-2x)(1-3x)\cdots(1-rx)}$$ 
 Can someone please tell me how to break this expression into partial fractions (because I am a bit weak at it) to find the following $$\sum_{r=2}^\infty T_r$$

Comment: Did you start by considering $T_2$ followed by $T_3$?

Comment: Sorry I have now edited the question

Comment: I don't know immediately how to decompose that expression into partial fractions, but I would start just the way abiessu suggests, doing it with $T_2$ and $T_3$ and maybe $T_4$ or further. If I see a pattern, I might try to prove by mathematical induction on $r$ that the pattern continues.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your method I couldn't understand what you mean to say about induction

Comment: So this one does telescope, it just takes some work to find the right decomposition...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sum is telescopic with a different decomposition as follows:

$$\begin{align}
T_r&=\frac{rx}{\prod\limits_{k=1}^r1-kx}=\frac{1}{\prod\limits_{k=1}^{r}1-kx}-\frac{1-rx}{\prod\limits_{k=1}^{r}1-kx}=\frac{1}{\prod\limits_{k=1}^{r}1-kx}-\frac{1}{\prod\limits_{k=1}^{r-1}1-kx}
\end{align}$$

It should be fairly clear that $-\frac 1{1-x}$ stays and all other terms telescope to $0$.  It is also interesting to note that if we begin the sum at $r=1$, we get the result $-1={x-1\over1-x}$.  For an approach on how to decompose all the terms directly, read on:

$$\begin{align}T_2&=\frac {2x}{(1-x)(1-2x)}=\frac A{1-2x}+\frac B{1-x}\\
2x &= A(1-x)+B(1-2x)\to A=-B=2\\
T_2&=\frac 2{1-2x}-\frac 2{1-x}\\
T_3=\frac 32T_2\frac 1{1-3x}&=\frac 3{(1-2x)(1-3x)}-\frac 3{(1-x)(1-3x)}\\
&=\frac 9{1-3x}-\frac 6{1-2x}-\frac 9{2(1-3x)}+\frac 3{2(1-x)}\\
T_4=\frac 43T_3\frac 1{1-4x}&=\frac 6{(1-3x)(1-4x)}-\frac 8{(1-2x)(1-4x)}+\frac 2{(1-x)(1-4x)}\\
&=\dots
\end{align}$$

Comment: Very nice solution !

Answer (score 1):

$$ T_{r}(x) = \frac{rx}{\displaystyle{\prod_{k=1}^{r}(1-kx)}}  $$

> The main idea is to decompose like this:
>   $$\frac{rx}{\displaystyle{\prod_{k=1}^{r}(1-kx)}} =\frac{A}{\displaystyle{\prod_{i=1}^{r-1}(1-ix)}}+\frac{B}{\displaystyle{\prod_{j={2}}^{r}(1-jx)}}$$
>   $$=\frac{A}{(1-x)(1-2x)\cdots(1-(r-1)x)}+\frac{B}{(1-2x)(1-3x)\cdots(1-rx)} $$
>   $$ \frac{rx}{\displaystyle{\prod_{k=1}^{r}(1-kx)}} = 
> \frac{A}{\displaystyle{\prod_{i=1}^{r-1}(1-ix)}}+\frac{B}{\displaystyle{\prod_{j=2}^{r}(1-jx)}}
> =\frac{A\cdot (1-rx)}{(1-rx)\displaystyle{\prod_{i=1}^{r-1}(1-ix)}}+\frac{B\cdot (1-x)}{\displaystyle{(1-x)\prod_{j=2}^{r}(1-jx)}}
> = \frac{(-B-rA)x+(A+B)}{\displaystyle{\prod_{k=1}^{r}(1-kx)}}$$

Then

$$A=\frac{r}{1-r}$$
$$B=\frac{-r}{1-r}$$

At least you can decompose as follows:

$$ T_{r}(x)= \frac{r}{1-r}\left(\frac{1}{\displaystyle{\prod_{j=1}^{r-1}(1-jx)}}-\frac{1}{\displaystyle{\prod_{j=2}^{r}(1-jx)}}\right) $$
$$T_{r}(x)=\left(\frac{\displaystyle{\frac{r}{1-r}}}{\displaystyle{\prod_{j=1}^{r-1}(1-jx)}}-\frac{\displaystyle{\frac{r}{1-r}}}{\displaystyle{\prod_{j=2}^{r}(1-jx)}}\right)$$

Comment: How big should $r$ be before I see the telescoping start?

Comment: I think it should be at least 2.

Comment: @abiessu: Then you are ok.

Comment: @abiessu: See this for instance: http://www.stumblingrobot.com/2016/02/29/prove-that-the-sum-from-1-to-of-n-n1n2n3-14/

Comment: I must be making a mistake with my algebra; I see a $\frac A{1-2x}+\frac B{1-3x}+\frac C{1-4x}+\dots$ set of terms in every $T_r$, so is there some sort of alternating telescoping happening?  It certainly cannot telescope for every $r$...

Comment: Oh, I see the mistake! The $j=2$ product is not equivalent to $T_{r+1}$!

Comment: @abiessu: Excellent :)

Comment: In particular this means that the sum is not telescopic, at least via the method you show...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68783/discussion-between-abiessu-and-hector-blandin).

Comment: @abiessu: Exactly it is not telescopic

Comment: @abiessu: I have to edit the answer

Comment: I was mistaken, the series does telescope, just with a different fraction decomposition...  your work was helpful in determining the correct algebra.

Comment: Excellent !  I would love to see the new solution to learn more. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

This simplifies down pretty nicely with an algebra package.  I think the other answers give you the right approach to attempt this by hand.

[image]

for x<>0.

Comment: This is false for the partial sums up to $T_4$, and perhaps the algebra package is making a mistake similar to what is seen below, that $T_{r+1}$ does not equate to a product starting at $j=2$.  Or perhaps the full sum really does converge nicely, but not in a telescoping manner...

Comment: The full sum really does converge nicely.

Comment: I think I can see it, that all the numerators go to $0$ except the $\frac A{1-x}$ term...